# Testing html files using Selenium and IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

How can I use selenium to open up html files on my machine on a browser besides Firefox? When starting Selenium, the baseUrl is set to either a real website (www.google.com) and the initial open command of the test points to the local html file

```
selenium.open("file:///C:/to/local/file.html")
```

or the baseUrl is set directly to the local html file and the initial line in the test is

```
selenium.open("/")
```

Is there a way to run these tests with the browser set to *iexplore that will not crash selenium?

Comment: Your file url is malformed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freeassociations/archive/2005/05/19/420059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tests all start as http requests to talk to the Selenium Proxy server. Internet Explorer won't allow Selenium to use Javascript from http when it opens a page using file:///

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#the-same-origin-policy